# Ubuntu 16.10 onward and derivatives do not query assigned DNS

Tags: dns

My DNS is separate to the gateway; gateway is at 192.168.3.1 and I run a DNSMASQ instance at 192.168.3.2. Ubuntu 16.04 and derivatives resolved static assigned and reserved hostnames on my LAN. Starting Ubuntu 16.10 resolution of LAN addresses fails, see below which shows 16.04 resolves, 18.04 and Pop!_OS 19.04 fail, and  other distros - Fedora 31, openSUSE Leap 15.1, and Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) - all resolve as expected.  Manjaro also resolves, though that's not shown here.

I think this is a bug, but before filing a bug report I thought I'd check among the experts whether it's a known issue already - my searching finds several instances of related issues, but nothing that goes to what I think is the heart of the matter - 16.10 and later do not query the assigned DNS server.

Is there a fix (as opposed to a workaround) for this, or should I proceed and file a bug report?

```
 Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
           Kernel: Linux 4.4.0-170-generic
 IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.3.2
 Server:        127.0.1.1
 Address:   127.0.1.1#53
 Name:  BGOWIKI01v
 Address: 192.168.3.60
 ============================================================================
 Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 4.15.0-72-generic
 IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.3.2
 Server:        127.0.0.53
 Address:   127.0.0.53#53
 ** server can't find BGOWIKI01v: SERVFAIL
 ============================================================================
 Operating System: Pop!_OS 19.04
            Kernel: Linux 5.0.0-21-generic
 IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.3.2
 Server:        127.0.0.53
 Address:   127.0.0.53#53
 ** server can't find BGOWIKI01v: SERVFAIL
 ============================================================================
 Operating System: Fedora 31 (Workstation Edition)
            Kernel: Linux 5.3.7-301.fc31.x86_64
 IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.3.2
 Server:        192.168.3.2
 Address:   192.168.3.2#53
 Name:  BGOWIKI01v
 Address: 192.168.3.60
 ============================================================================
 Operating System: openSUSE Leap 15.1
            Kernel: Linux 4.12.14-lp151.28.36-default
 IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.3.2
 Server:        192.168.3.2
 Address:   192.168.3.2#53
 Name:  BGOWIKI01v
 Address: 192.168.3.60
 ============================================================================
 Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
            Kernel: Linux 4.19.0-6-amd64
 IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.3.2
 Server:        192.168.3.2
 Address:   192.168.3.2#53
 Name:  BGOWIKI01v
 Address: 192.168.3.60
```

Answer (score 0):

Bug report has been submitted, here -  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1862437